# Playlist with contents in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, has-many-through, playlist

I want to create a Playlist concept in my Ruby on Rails application. At the moment, all I have is a `Content` model, that's what will be in the playlists.

I already know the associations I need, and I'm using `through:` because I need an `order` attribute in the join table, to know the order of the **contents** in each **playlist**.

```
class Playlist < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :contents_playlists
    has_many :contents, through: :contents_playlists
end

class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :contents_playlists
    has_many :playlists, through: :contents_playlists
end

class ContentsPlaylist < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :content
    belongs_to :playlist
end
```

My problem is that I'm no pro in RoR and about this associations I know the theory (already read the Rails Guides about this) but I can't put it to execution without errors. I guess it's because I'm losing something.

I searched and searched for tutorials and examples with code but found nothing. So, I'm asking for some help for doing that: how to add that attribute to the join table (I've created it with a `scaffold` but I bet that's not the recommended...), and how to manage the views and controllers to give me an interface to **add a content to a playlist** and to see the **contents in a playlist, with the order**.

Comment: What is the errors you are getting?

Comment: The errors happened when I tried to build a view to create a `ContentsPlaylist` form, with a `content_id`, `playlist_id` and `order`. My guess is that I don't really know how to create the `ContentsPlaylist` table with the `order` attribute and I don´t know how to use the associations later. My goal is to have a view where I can add a `content` to a `playlist` with a `order` (position). I'm not being able to do it.

Comment: If it is order then here is a gem you can look into: acts_as_list, http://railscasts.com/episodes/147-sortable-lists-revised

Comment: I only want `Content`s to be ordered when they are in a playlist. There will be more than one playlist, so... I've already seen that episode, but that's not exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Your has many name is wrong, should it be content_playlists instead of contents_playlists

```
class Playlist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :content_playlists
  has_many :contents, through: :content_playlists
end

class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :content_playlists
  has_many :playlists, through: :content_playlists
end

class ContentPlaylist < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :content
  belongs_to :playlist
end
```

Comment: It was a typo in the question. Thanks for noticing. I've edited the question.